# Make a bold version of a regular ttf font

Tags: truetype

I have a ttf font file. (unicode character set) Having no other option, I had to use it in a tex file. But unfortunately this font doesn't have any bold version. And in the tex file I failed to produce any bold or italic text with the commands like \textit and \textbf.

Is it possible to make a bold (and italic) version from an existing font file?

Answer (score 0):

Open office will do that. i have one ttf file, individigitalis, and openoffice will make it into italic.But Gimp will need a complete italic ttf file to display that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use a font editor like FontLab Studio.